# Angular :Is there a way to access all the form controls in a form from the ts file without explicitlly passing it form html?

Tags: angular, typescript

HTML code

```
<form #pharmacyForm="ngForm" name="form" novalidate>
//form controls
         <button (click)="onSubmit(pharmacyForm)">Save</button>
</form>
```

TypeScript code

```
onSubmit(pharmacyForm){
    const controls = pharmacyForm.controls;
    for(const name in controls){
      if (controls[name].invalid) {

        controls[name].touched=true;
    }
    }
    if (pharmacyForm.valid) {
      this.save();
   }

  }
```

Now I have multiple methods in my TypeScript file which indirectly invokes onSubmit and I dont want to pass pharmacyForm as an argument to each of these methods . I just want to able to access the form without passing it as method argument.Like binding the form object to a variable then be able to iterate its controls,How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a reference to the form you can use, the @ViewChild decorator.

```
@ViewChild('pharmacyForm') public form: NgForm;

onSubmit() {
 console.log(this.form);
}
```